# Using Coordinator layout for creating Collapsing Toolbar and Recycler View

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have been trying to use Coordinator layout to create a collapsing toolbar and include a layout using Recycler view, but the toolbar is not collapsing. Could someone point out what i'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Here is the code: 
activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:elevation="4dp">


    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:background="#205052"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/anim_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                android:text="hello"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity = "fill_vertical"
android:layout_marginBott`enter code here`om="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:layout_behavior = "@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
<include layout="@layout/recycler"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

recycler.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/fragment_horizontal_recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_horizontal_recycler_view2">
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_horizontal_recycler_view3"
    >
</android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` for `<android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout />`